# How to use instancing and world translation together?

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm trying to optimize my application, so I've started to use instancing to save myself from multiple draw calls for the same object.
But what I'm not being able to understand is how do I position each instanced object on the right position, I've been learning from Rastertek tutorials and this is their shader code:

```
struct VertexInputType
{
    float4 position : POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
    float3 instancePosition : TEXCOORD1;
};

struct PixelInputType
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float2 tex : TEXCOORD0;
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Vertex Shader
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
PixelInputType TextureVertexShader(VertexInputType input)
{
    PixelInputType output;


// Change the position vector to be 4 units for proper matrix calculations.
    input.position.w = 1.0f;

// Update the position of the vertices based on the data for this particular instance.
    input.position.x += input.instancePosition.x;
    input.position.y += input.instancePosition.y;
    input.position.z += input.instancePosition.z;

// Calculate the position of the vertex against the world, view, and projection matrices.
    output.position = mul(input.position, worldMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, viewMatrix);
    output.position = mul(output.position, projectionMatrix);

// Store the texture coordinates for the pixel shader.
    output.tex = input.tex;

    return output;
}
```

I've been using `XMMatrixTranslation` from `DirectXMath.h` on my world matrix to put each object on place, but now looks like the instanced objects have to get their coordinates directly on the shader and as I'm aware of this will be done for each vertex on each instance.

This really got me confused, what's the purpose of the world matrix if every instance of the object is already going to be placed in the world by `instancePosition`? If there's a way to keep using my world matrix to translate each instance of the same object to the world it would be many times better for me, but I don't know if it is possible, if anyone knows anything which could help me on this it would be great.

Comment: How many times are you drawing exactly the same object in a scene?

Comment: No expert here: I think the purpose of the matrix is still the same as it always has been: To convert the vertex positions from object to world space. You are essentially offsetting the position of each instance from the "original" position in object space and then use the same transformation matrix to convert those into world space.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I actually am creating a scene here, and for example a certain object is rendered 282 times in different places with different rotation and scale, another one is rendered 120 times, and it keeps going... The entire scene consists of 3000 objects, most of them are repeated some times, so I thought instancing these ones would improve my framerate, I am only getting around 25 fps without instancing. Is it a problem if I use instancing with objects that repeat only a few times?

Comment: @puelo Well, if it works this way then it makes sense, but I think in my case I won't need it then.